# Upgrading python

Tags: updates, python

Is it possible to update python without root access, this is the first time using red hat linux (any linux for that matter) and the default version is python 2.3 which breaks some of my code that i tested on python 2.6.

i tried building from source but it said i needed root access.

Comment: For what exactly is it needing root access? You should be able to make and make install python as long as you stay in your $HOME-dir.

Answer (score 6):

How did you compile the source? If you did `./configure`, do this instead:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

(`$HOME` should expand to something like `/home/burisum`.) In this way the third step (`make install`) will install the files in your homedir and you will not need root access.

Comment: i tried this but i get the message,

permission denied

Comment: Can you show that error message and some (say, 5) of the lines before it?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a "user" installation i.e. in your `~` directory.

Make sure you update your `.bashrc` (or equivalent) to insert the path to your interpreter in front of `/usr/bin` if you intend for your interpreter to serve as default for your session though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have access to the latest python modules without harming your system I would suggest using Anaconda.  [This](http://continuum.io/downloads) contains the latest python interpreter etc...  It installs in your home directory so that you have access to it and you don't need root permissions to use or install it.

I would let system update handle the systems package update process and not try to force anything (unless you just forgot the root password)